# Getting the nth values from a list to run through a list without a for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataset, range

`list_` contains many integers within it, I want to get the nth value of it. The nth values are contained in the `list_` var. So I would like to print `list_[10], list_[25], list_[45]....`. Is there a way that I could do this without using a `for-loop`, using the range function within a list perhaps `list_[:]`

```
list_ = [ 5268, 6760,  6761 ... 15149, 15150, 15151]
list_2= [10,25,45,60,90]
```

Comment: We can use recursion and slicing for this task and it doesn't require a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it only with `range` function.

The easiest way is this one:

```
result = [list_[i] for i in list_2]
print(result)
```

But here is some other ways: https://blog.finxter.com/python-list-arbitrary-indices/

Comment: This still makes use of for loop. How does this answer the question ?

Answer (score 0):

The best method to use in this case is `recursion` with the help of slicing. Any `iteration` task can be performed using `recursion` and since performance drawback is insignificant for this particular question, it makes sense to use `recursion`.

Say we have two lists `list_1` and `list_2`

```
def rec_increment(list_2,list_1):
    if len(list_2) == 0:
        return ""                                 #so that it doesn't print 'none' in the end   
    else:
        print(list_1[list_2[0]])                
        return rec_increment(list_2[1:],list_1)   #only recur on the 2nd-nth part of the list
list_1= [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
list_2= [1,2,4,5]
rec_increment(list_2,list_1)                  #gives 10 20 40 50
```

You can also make use of `forEach()` in java or even a while loop if the condition is only to not use a `for-loop`.

Comment: Please consider accepting the solution if it solved your problem.